# incrementing to numbers that are led by zeros

Tags: python, numbers

There are many questions regarding to turning an integer to a number led by zeros, But i couldn't find any solutions to incrementing string that is already led by zeros.

Python already transforms number led by zero to normal integer:

```
>>> 0001
1
>>> int(0001)
1
```

By considering that, whenever i add two numbers led by zero to each other, i get a normal integer:

```
>>> 0001 + 0001
2
>>> int('0001') + int('0001')
2
```

But, what i am trying to find out is for example, how to get a sum such as `0002` when adding two `0001`'s to each other.

Obviously it should be printed out as string type, since Python transforms number led by zero to normal integer.

Please also consider some cases like this:

`x = 0001`

How can i increment x by 1 without specifying zeros?

---

Is there any Pythonic way to do this? With solution working on all cases of numbers led by zero? (`'0001' + '0001' == '0002' and '01' + '01' == '02'`, For example).

Comment: The two strings that you are adding have always the same length?

Comment: @Jalo No, i am also looking for the cases where i only know one number length, for example x variable with value of `001` and i want to just increment it by 1, so the sum is - `002`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the strings have the same length, you can simply apply `zfill` on the output using the length of one of the operands:

```
def add(x, y) -> str: # remove type hint for Python 2
   return str(int(x) + int(y)).zfill(len(x))

print(add('0001', '0025'))
# '0026'
```

To accomodate string inputs of mismatching lengths, you can pass `max(len(x), len(y))` to `zfill` so that the output is *zero padded* using the length of the longer string:

```
def add(x, y) -> str:
   return str(int(x) + int(y)).zfill(max(len(x), len(y)))

print(add('0001', '25'))
# 0026
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i'm also looking for the cases where i know only x with value of `0001` and i want to increment it with `1` without specifying zeros.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
x = '00001'
y = '00002'

print '{0:0{width}}'.format(int(x)+int(y), width=max(len(x), len(y)))
```

prints `00003`

Comment: You may find `'{0:03}'.format(intval)`will suffice. 03 means a field of width 3, zero-padded. But if intval is too large, it'll take as many characters as it needs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what happens in cases when i know only `x` value - `00001` and i want to increment it just by 1, so value gets `00001` without specifying zeros.